# Subtract Timespan and Return Hour and Minute to Decimal

Tags: c#, .net-core, timespan

Good day everyone,

I'm trying to subtract a certain time to a grace period and return it as decimal hour and minute format.

Here's my code so far:

```
var hourAndMinute = 0.00M;

var gracePeriod = new TimeSpan(9,30,00);

var loggedIn = new TimeSpan(11,00,00); // dynamic data

hourAndMinute = loggedIn.Subtract(gracePeriod).Minutes;
```

But I'm getting a different result.

What I what is something like this,

```
1.30M = 1 hours and 30 minutes
```

But I don't know what to do.

Any help please?

Comment: do you want the result to be a string (as in "1 hours and 30 minutes"), or you want it as the "1.30M"?

Comment: What answer do you get and what answer do you want?

Comment: You're close. ```TimeSpan result  = loggedIn.Subtract(gracePeriod); ``` Output: ```Console.WriteLine($"{result.Hours} hours and {result.Minutes} minutes."); ```

Comment: `decimal result = hourAndMinute.Hours + hourAndMinute.Minutes / (decimal)100`?

Comment: 1.30M is not equal to 1 hours and 30 minutes,

Comment: You want output as string (`1 hours and 30 minutes`) or in decimal (`1.30M`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want output in this format, but for your requirement this should work.

```
hourAndMinute = (decimal)loggedIn.Subtract(gracePeriod).Hours + (decimal)loggedIn.Subtract(gracePeriod).Minutes/100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be 1.5 for 1 hour and 30 minutes? and Timespan already has that what you looking for is

```
loggedIn.Subtract(gracePeriod).TotalHours;
```

Comment: Just as a complement to Tiago Silva's answer, `Timespan` has some helper methods that might apply to what you are looking for. They are `.TotalDays`, `.TotalHours`, `.TotalMinutes` and `.TotalSeconds`. Beware that these are not to be confused with the `.Hours`, `.Minutes`, etc. since those are only looking at the specific part of the Timespan. For instance, the timespan `"01:30:00"` would output `1.5` for `.TotalHours`, and `1` for `.Hours`

Comment: I having a trouble. I tried to use this, so my data time is `'10:23:01' - '9:00:00'` the result is `'1.38'` which is wrong.

Comment: @AppleCiderYummy No, this is correct. The result 1.38361111111111 equals 1 hour + 0.38361111111111 hours, which is 0.38361111111111hours*60min/hour=23.016 Minutes and 0.016min*60sec/min is 1 second. Thats exactly the expected result of 1hour 23 minutes and 1 second.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `"10:23:01" - "09:00:00"` would result in `"01:23:01"`. This is actually equal to "1 hour" plus a fraction of hour that is lesser than 0.5, since 0.5 hour would be equal to 30 minutes. With that being said, I think that is the expected behavior.